# Multiple Select statement using COUNT

Tags: sql, oracle, aggregate-functions

I'm trying to combine these two select queries but the count function is confusing me with Oracle:

```
select person.first_name, COUNT(person.PERSON_ID) as Active
FROM incident, person
where person.PERSON_ID = incident.OWNER_ID
and incident.incident_id = 1
AND (incident.dept_id = 111 OR incident.dept_id = 222)
GROUP BY person.first_name;


select person.first_name, COUNT(person.PERSON_ID) as NonActive
FROM incident, person
where person.PERSON_ID = incident.OWNER_ID
AND incident.incident_id = 2
AND (incident.dept_id = 111OR incident.dept_id = 222)
GROUP BY person.first_name
```

I'm trying to return a single result as:

```
FIRST_NAME ACTIVE NonActive
Bob          5       11
John         3       14
```

What would be the best (efficient) way of doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are two ways to do it. I pretty sure SUM CASE will be better but you can test it yourself

Using SUM CASE

```
select person.first_name, 
SUM(case when incident.incident_id =1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Active,
SUM(case when incident.incident_id =2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS NonActive,

FROM incident, person
where person.PERSON_ID = incident.OWNER_ID

   AND (incident.dept_id = 111 OR incident.dept_id = 222)
   AND incident.incident_id IN (1,2)

GROUP BY person.first_name;
```

Using JOIN

```
SELECT  DISTINCT
    p.First_name,
    Acive.Active,
    NonActive.NonActive
FROM
PERSON p

LEFT JOIN 
(
select person.first_name, COUNT(person.PERSON_ID) as Active
FROM incident, person
where person.PERSON_ID = incident.OWNER_ID
and incident.incident_id = 1
AND (incident.dept_id = 111 OR incident.dept_id = 222)
GROUP BY person.first_name;
) Active
ON p.first_name = active.first_name
LEFT JOIN 
(
select person.first_name, COUNT(person.PERSON_ID) as NonActive
FROM incident, person
where person.PERSON_ID = incident.OWNER_ID
AND incident.incident_id = 2
AND (incident.dept_id = 111OR incident.dept_id = 222)
GROUP BY person.first_name
) NonActive

ON p.first_name = NonActive.first_name

where Active.First_name is not null
and NonActive.First_name is not null
```

Comment: Great! How do I exlude rows that have 0 values for both columns from the results?

Comment: @madlan  Added `AND incident.incident_id IN (1,2)` to the where clause for the first one. I think the second one already does this

Comment: The join seems to return multiple results (rows) for the same people?

Comment: Sorry You'll need to add a `DISTINCT`

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want to do your count on the incident_id instead of person_id; that way, you can combine your two queries into one and get the result you want.